# SHA-256 digest error for org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Sequence$1.class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-17

I'm using lib:

```
'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
```

My App java version is 17

i got this error:  [image]

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text and include it formatted as code into your question.